# microsoft office will not let me open Word

Tags: microsoft-office

I do not want to try office and I do not want to buy it. There is no way to choose the option of not wanting either. I just want to use WORD to edit a rtf file. How the hell do I stop the pop up from coming up?

Comment: Word is part of Microsoft Office.

Comment: music2myear's answer addresses Word.  If your requirement is just to edit rtf files, you don't need Word.  There are any number of free editors and word processors that will do it.  Windows own WordPad is one.  AbiWord is a lightweight word processor.  Other office suites, like LibreOffice and WPS Office handle rtf.  All or most of those are cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use Microsoft Word you must have a license to it.

Microsoft Word is a part of the Microsoft Office suite.

Microsoft Office has not been included with new computers for several years now. You'll often find a trial version (such as you appear to have found) but it is time limited.

If you are in the US, these are the options for purchasing Microsoft Office: https://products.office.com/en-US/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?&activetab=tab%3aprimaryr1